# Sharepoint folder user access control

Tags: sharepoint

I have a requirement to restrict access to SharePoint folders for certain users, where there 1000 users with SharePoint access, but only 100 users can access a certain SharePoint folder for example. Any ideas on how to manage this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unique permission for the folder.

Go to the document library -> Select the folder -> Manage access -> Advanced -> Stop Inheriting permissions -> Remove users who cannot access folder.